# Install Lubuntu 12.04 from ISO stored within current installation

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, lubuntu, iso

I have an older PC running Lubuntu 14.04 and it's pretty messed up. There's no background, all the icons are broken, I'm surprised it's still even booting.

This is an issue that cropped up when I installed 14.04 fresh. 12.04 had been working just fine, so I have decided I'm just going to go back to that and give up on trying to fix my current install.

I've downloaded the correct 12.04 ISO and was somewhat curious as to whether or not I can install 12.04 over 14.04, from the current location where the 12.04 ISO is stored (within the current, 14.04 installation.)

I know you can boot an ISO stored on a hard drive/USB drive, even without actually writing the files to the drive via something like Unetbootin or USB Creator but I want to know whether or not I can boot the ISO from where it's stored in the 14.04 installation and then use it to install 12.04.

The specs are pretty measly on this ancient laptop (mid 2005 - 1.3 GHz processor, 512MB RAM) so I doubt I could load the installer fully into RAM.

I'm figuring that this is actually impossible, seeing as I'd have to overwrite the partition the ISO is stored on in order to install 12.04, but I was curious as to whether or not this was actually possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can boot an iso from a partition with grub only if the iso is modified to do so. It takes a long time to boot and runs slowly. You can not install into the partition the iso is stored on , but you can install it on an alternate partitoin.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot